# Confusing token syntaxes

Tags: bash, awk, syntax, syntax-error, syntax-highlighting

Trying to create a command in a script that prints out a command in plain text, as well executing an example of what it does, but what's throwing me off is the stupid syntax characters involving `('`

it tells me

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

in this command

```
openssl rand -base64 37 | awk BEGIN{FS=””} for (i=1; i<=37; i++) printf( "%s",$i );} {printf "\n"}'
```

I've read in various places that you need to double quote `"` these things or something like that, but it's not working. I don't see where the issue is here, it should just WORK, I tried adding doubles `"` singles `'` and `(( ))` but they don't even work. it makes no sense why it's complaining about `('`. I have this opened up in Sublime Text and it doesn't show me any syntax errors here, since it has syntax highlighting for Bash, and it would show me if there is a syntax error or not, and it's clearly not.

Answer (score 2):

You will save yourself tons of trouble if you start small and build out, rather than write a complete command and then try to debug it.

Right now, this is the command you should have:

```
openssl rand -base64 37 | awk ''
```

Then you can start adding to it:

```
openssl rand -base64 37 | awk 'BEGIN{}'
```

So far so good, now add more:

```
$ openssl rand -base64 37 | awk 'BEGIN{FS=””}'
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
         >>> BEGIN{FS=� <<<
```

And now you've narrowed one problem down to the `FS=””` part, instead of trying to debug three separate syntax errors in an 80 character command at the same time:

1. You need an opening `'`
2. You have to use ascii quotes, not slanted unicode quotes
3. You're missing an opening `{` before your for loop.

But you can just simplify all this with `head -c`:

```
openssl rand -base64 37  | head -c 37
```

Comment: I'm not even using the slanted quotes`” ”` , it keeps inputting that itself when I copy + paste it from one thing to another. It's so broken. Keeps converting `"` into slanted double quotes `”`

Comment: @user94959 How annoying! If you're using macOS, google for "how to disable smart quotes". If not, get a programming oriented text editor instead of a word processor.

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text 3 on Linux Mint which is built for coding in.

Comment: Do they appear when you copy from an online blog/book/something maybe? Not all programming blogs remember to turn off their CMS's fancy quote setting.

Comment: I tired a few different online awk interpreters, and I think they kept converting them.

Comment: Is it your browser doing it?